# C# WPF Anyway to Embed a PDF within an Exe?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, embedded-resource

Having read up on this issue for a few hours, I am coming round to the idea that it is not possible to embed a PDF file into the Executable itself - that the only way it happens is by having an "associated" folder that you have to pass along with the executable.

However, before I entirely scrap the idea, I thought I would check here to see if anyone knows of a workaround?

I am not looking for the user to open the PDF in a PDF reader, I am using WebBrowser to display the PDF - which works fine - but when compiling into an Executable using Fody - it produces a Folder called "Resources" and if I move the standalone Executable elsewhere (despite being almost exactly the size of the PDF larger than a compiled executable without the PDF) it says it cannot find the PDF.

I was wondering whether the workaround is have a URI that is in a different location to the Resource folder? - but I don't know how to do that and have not been able to find a way of doing it.

The PDF is a static document - instructions - that is unchanging.

I have read a LOT of responses on here - it is what I have been doing for the past few hours - but none of them really answer this question.

Can you embed a PDF for display in a WPF application and have a standalone executable?

Steps I have taken:

1. Bring the PDF into the WPF C# .NET Framework 4.7.2 application as a Resource using the Resource.resx system.
2. Marking it as Embedded Resource/Resource/Content (I tried all 3)
3. Marking it as Copy Always/Never/If Newer (I tried all 3)

Code Block

XAML

```
<WebBrowser x:name="pdfWebviewer"/>
```

Code Behind

```
pdfWebviewer.Navigate("blank::about")
pdfWebviewer.Navigate("pack://application:,,,/Test.pdf")
```

This code is from memory so forgive me if there is an error in capitalisation or something.

This code will display the PDF - but only if you have the Resources folder in the same location as the Executable - and if I am going to do that, I might as well just give people the PDF...

If anyone knows a workaround would appreciate it.

Comment: Im sure you could embed if you publish as a single file

Comment: Does this help? [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)

Comment: Appreciate the link, but I am aware of other ways to deploy - but due to infosec having anything that 'installs' is a massive pain. - Also with Fody, the file size is about 300kb - a single file deployment using Microsoft methods is 155mb - same app, does the same thing, just 500 times larger.  For a single PDF addition not worth the sacrifice for either of those options.